# Запятая в безличном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Ничего нет(,) и меня нет заодно со всем этим.

Два безличных предложения, соединенные союзом и. Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна, так как это сложносочиненное предложение. Оба безличных предложения "равноправны".

Comment: а это не простое предложение с повторяющимся сказуемым?

Comment: наподобие "нет меня и нет тебя"

Comment: Запятая нужна, она нужна и в предложении "Нет меня, и нет тебя". Запятая между безличными предложениями не ставится в редких случаях -  например,когда они явно напоминают однородные члены:Меня сорвало с якоря   и понесло.Промозгло  и мутно, туманно и вьюжно.

Comment: > Запятая между безличными предложениями не ставится в редких случаях - например,когда они явно напоминают однородные члены

Интересно было бы узнать, кому мы обязаны этим положением. Розенталь, например, "редкие случаи", когда запятая между безличными предложениями не ставится, ограничивает теми случаями, когда безличные предложения имеют синонимические слова в составе сказуемых. К слову, в данном случае, по-моему, это условие выполняется со всей строгостью.

Comment: Тема однородных односоставных предложений разработана очень подробно, и она весьма логична. Здесь дело не только в формальных правилах, а и в структуре предложения, когда однородные предложения фактически являются однородными членами. А для этого требуется их грамматическая и смысловая однородность: один производитель действия, даже одна ситуация.НАПРИМЕР:Меня допросили   и сразу отпустили.    Ходишь по лесу и думаешь о чём-то своём.

Comment: НО:Было тихо, светло,  и чуть подмораживало.О приезде гостей сообщили поздно, и в доме ничего не успели приготовить. А в нашем предложении сходная грамматика, но совершенно различная семантика - отрицание разных объектов.

Answer (score 0):

По Розенталю не должно быть запятой:
3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
...
5) односоставные безличные предложения, имеющие синонимичные слова: Необходимо рассмотреть авторские заявки и надо срочно составить по ним заключения.